# show same size button in all devices

Tags: android

I have made button with 25dpiX25dpi for mobile device.  but when I run it on tablet it become small.
what should I do to auto adjust button as per screen size?

Thank You.

Comment: Have a look @ http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: First of all I want to know how exactly you want to put your button on screen.

Comment: can you post your code/xml that how you placed the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change 25dp for 25px (or more)

This is the formula:

```
float scale = ctx.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
int pixels = (int) (25 * scale + 0.5f); //convert 35 dp to pixels
```